# fill oceans for basemap in 3D

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

I would like to fill oceans for my basemap in 3D but

```
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua'))
```

doesn't seem to work because the basemap drawmapboundary method doesn’t return an object supported by add_collection3d but a *matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection* object. Is there any workaround similar to the one done for land polygons [here](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html#filling-the-polygons)? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow`.  Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a rectangle (polygon) below the map is one solution. Here is the working code that you may try.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

map = Basemap()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.azim = 270
ax.elev = 50
ax.dist = 8

ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.20))
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.15))

polys = []
for polygon in map.landpolygons:
    polys.append(polygon.get_coords())

# This fills polygons with colors
lc = PolyCollection(polys, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.3, \
                    facecolor='#BBAAAA', alpha=1.0, closed=False)
lcs = ax.add_collection3d(lc, zs=0)  # set zero zs

# Create underlying blue color rectangle
# It's `zs` value is -0.003, so it is plotted below land polygons
bpgon = np.array([[-180., -90],
       [-180, 90],
       [180, 90],
       [180, -90]])
polys2 = []
polys2.append(bpgon)
lc2 = PolyCollection(polys2, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0.1, \
                    facecolor='#445599', alpha=1.0, closed=False)
lcs2 = ax.add_collection3d(lc2, zs=-0.003)  # set negative zs value

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]